# How to access 64-bit Windows environment variables from 32-bit Python?

Tags: python, windows, x86, 64-bit

Is there some reasonably straightforward way to read the 64 bit Windows environment variables from 32 bit Python?

For example, the default value of

```
os.environ['ProgramFiles']
```

is r'C:\Program Files' in a 32 bit environment (and that's what os.environ reports in a 32 bit Python), but it's r'C:\Program Files (x86)' in a 64-bit environment.

I want to get at the 64-bit version of the variables from a 32-bit Python. How?

===================================================================

This part of the question is a pre-emptive rant for those of you who can't wait to say *"Why do you want to do that?"* or *"It's not a good idea to do that"*, instead of answering the question.

I have good and sufficient reasons for asking. I'm using Python to automate setup of Windows boxes. They might be running either 32 bit or 64 bit Windows, so only 32 bit Python can be sure to run on both. But the value of the 64 bit variables matters, because they determine where certain files should go.

And - before you say "just put things in "C:\Program Files" if it's a 32-bit Windows or "C:\Program Files (x86)" if it's a 64-bit Windows, let me point out that these environment variables exist for a reason. While those locations may be correct 99% of the time, users may have moved these folders to other drive letters or other locations.

There's no point in having the environment variables to tell you where things go if nobody looks at them. :-)

Comment: This is almost certainly not going to be specific to Python; by including that tag, you're scaring away PowerShell, VB, etc. experts who are probably more likely to know the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ProgramW6432` environment variable to get the real (64-bit) path of `Program Files` if you're a 32-bit program running on a 64-bit version of Windows:

```
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
```

.. while running under a 32-bit OS won't have the variable set.

So in python, something like:

```
path = os.environ['ProgramW6432'] if 'ProgramW6432' in os.environ else os.environ['ProgramFiles']
```

.. should work as you want it to.

Comment: That's a good answer for the specific case of the 'ProgramFiles' variable, but is there a general solution?

Comment: @nerdfever.com: The question was revolving around *%ProgramFiles%*. There are others in the same situation (e.g. *%PROCESSOR\_ARCHITECTURE%*). But not all. Yo might get the others from the registry. *WOW64*  topic partially covers this scenario as well.

Comment: @nerdfever.com There really isn't anything like "give me what a 32-bit windows would set these values to" - that's generally what wow64 tries to do, and you're asking to work around that. In that case you'll have to take it case by case - those variables that are relevant for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MatsLindh I think you're misunderstanding what I'm trying to do. I want the actual (not hypothetical) values of the 64-bit env variables, when I'm actually on a 64 bit OS (but running a 32-bit process). Not "what a 32-bit windows would to", but instead what the 64-bit Windows actually does.